# Removing line if it has a string

Tags: php

```
    this is a sentence oil on a line
    this is another sentence
    another one
    hey oil sentence
```

I have these 4 sentences, what I want to do is to check if this sentence(each sentence is on a line) has the word `oil`. And if it does I would delete the whole sentence.

So I'll End up with this:

```
    this is another sentence
    another one
```

the lines including `oil` has been removed.

I had an idea of `exploding` these lines to an array. Then use `foreach` to check for `oil`. Deleting the element, then `imploding`.

But I was wondering if there are any faster ways?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. Here is a related question: [How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words).

Answer (score 0):

While your idea with `explode` would work, there are easier ways. You can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to find a substring within a string. If no substring is found it will return false. If you want case insensitivity you can for the original string to be all lowercase (or uppercase) with [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower) (or [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) ):

```
if( strpos(strtolower($string),'oil')!==false )
{
    // string found
}
else
{
    // string not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strpos()` function in php, if that particular string has a position then that means that your string has that particular word or character.

Just have a look at a simple solution as per your requirement

```
 foreach( explode($wholesentence,"\n" ) as $yourstrimg )
    if (strpos($yourstrimg,'oil') !== false) {
        echo 'oil';
    }
}
```

**Note:**

`"\n"` is just used to indicate new line here, it can also be different line break operator change in different languages, like in html it is `"<br />"`